# Calculate impulse response for given system

Tags: signal-processing

i am given an exercise in which i need to find the impulse response for this given system:

$$y(n) = 2x(n-2) + x(n) -2x(n+2)$$

This is the only information i have. 
I don't even understand which formula should be applied to get the result.

May any merciful soul help me on my way to find the solution? :)

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide more context please? what are or you think are $x(n), y(n)$? is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Blex i guess we can assume n ∈ ℝ, since it was not specified. It was just said this is the input-output relation and that the system response to an impulse should be calculated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to apply an impulse input (i.e. $x(n) = \delta (n)$), and see what is the response $y(n)$ (It is usually called $h(n)$). In this case, as the output does not depend on its self, you simply obtain:
$$h(n) = \delta (n) + 2 \delta (n-2) - 2 \delta (n+2) $$
From this impulse response you can obtain the response for any input.